# Estimate the asymptotic efficiency of a Markov chain sampling by the method of batching

Tags: autocorrelation, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings, optimal-scaling

In the paper [Efficient Metropolis Jumping Rules](http://people.ee.duke.edu/~lcarin/baystat5.pdf), the author is writing that he used "the method of batching" for the estimation of $\operatorname{eff}_{\overline\theta_i}$ in Table 1 (on page 605). Could somebody explain to me what he is actually meaning? By the [answer to my other question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/395276/222528), it is clear to me how we can compute the autocorrelation of a one-dimensional set of samples at any lag. How do we estimate $\operatorname{eff}_{\overline\theta_i}$ from that?

Answer (score 4):

I assume the authors are talking about the "batch means estimators" which are very popular in steady state simulation and MCMC.

Suppose $X_1, X_2, \dots X_N$ are from a Markov chain with stationary distribution $\pi$ with mean $\theta$ and variance $\tau^2$. Let $\bar{\theta}$ be the sample average. Then if the samples had been iid, the variance of $\bar{\theta}$ would have been $\tau^2/N$. But since they are not iid, the variance is something else, dentoed by $V_{\bar{\theta}}$. Specifically
$$ \lim_{N \to \infty} N \text{Var}(\bar{\theta}) = V_{\bar{\theta}}$$

So $V_{\bar{\theta}}$ is the asymptotic variance of $\bar{\theta}$. In other words, if a Markov chain CLT holds, then
$$ \sqrt{N}(\bar{\theta} - \theta) \overset{d}{\to} N(0, V_{\bar{\theta}})$$

The authors then define 
$$ 
\text{eff}_{\bar{\theta}} = \dfrac{\tau^2}{V_{\bar{\theta}}}\,,
$$
as an assessment of how well the Markov chain is mixing. (Note, this efficiency is very similar to [effective sample size](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296059/effective-sample-size-greater-than-actual-sample-size/315874#315874) )

In order to estimate $\text{eff}_{\bar{\theta}}$, we need an estimate of $\tau^2$ and $V_{\bar{\theta}}$. Note that since $\tau^2$ is the variance of the target distribution $\pi$, the sample variance is the default estimator of $\tau^2$. Thus, the main difficulty is in estimating $V_{\bar{\theta}}$.

From the paper it can be easily concluded that $V_{\bar{\theta}}$ has the following specific form:
$$V_{\bar{\theta}} = \tau^2 + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \text{Cov}(X_1, X_{1+k})\,. $$

You would think that according to the structure of $V_{\bar{\theta}}$, we must estimate each of the lag covariances $\text{Cov}(X_1, X_{1+k})$, up until some finite $K$, and then sum them up. However, this is unknown to be a highly variable estimator. To stabilize the estimator, one can weight the covariances and then add them up, and that leads to  the spectral variance estimators (also highly popular).

However, a simple estimator is the batch means estimator, which makes use of the idea that means inside each batch mimic the overall mean. That is, let's break the sample into $a$ number of batches, each of size $b$ $(N = ab)$.
$$\underbrace{X_1, \dots X_b}_{\bar{Y}_1}, \underbrace{X_{b+1}, \dots X_{2b}}_{\bar{Y}_2} \dots \underbrace{X_{(a-1)b+1}, \dots X_{ab}}_{\bar{Y}_a}\,. $$

Inside each batch, calculate the average of the batch, $\bar{Y}_i$$i = 1, \dots, a$. Then note that each $\bar{Y}_i$ is a Monte Carlo estimator of $\theta$, and if $b$ increases with $N$, each batch mean also has a Markov chain CLT. So
$$\sqrt{b}(\bar{Y}_i - \theta) \overset{d}{\to}N(0, V_{\bar{\theta}})\,, $$
The limiting variance is the same because at infinite samples $\bar{Y}_i$ is indistinguishable from $\bar{\theta}$.

Thus, now we have $\bar{Y}_1, \dots, \bar{Y}_a$  all dependent (but almost independent for large $b$), with mean $\theta$ and variance $V_{\bar{\theta}}/b$. So to estimate $V_{\bar{\theta}}$, we can get the sample variance of the batch means and rescale by $b$. That is

$$BM_{\theta} = \dfrac{b}{a-1} \sum_{i=1}^{a} (\bar{Y}_i - \bar{\theta})^2\,. $$

This is called the batch means estimator. The role of $b$ is essentially the same as the role of $K$, both of which must grow with $N$ for strong consistency of estimators. You can find details of the estimators, results and conditions of consistency all [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.1729v5.pdf).

Comment: (+1) I was going to suggest the Flegal & Jones reference as well! There is also an [older paper by Hobert et al. (2002)](https://academic.oup.com/biomet/article/89/4/731/242209).